# Calculating the sum of your name given every letter a number

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve this program which aims to ask the user to enter his name while given every letter of the alphabet a number e.i(a=1,b=2...) then calculate the sum of the name (Using arrays and strings)
This is the code I've tried Can someone help me with it. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
int letters [] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
int sum, i, j, count=0;
char numbers [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26};   
char name [50];
char ch;
printf("Enter a name --> ");
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
scanf("%c", name [i]);
++count;
}
for(j=0;j<=count;j++){
    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        if(name [j] == letters [i])
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
}
printf("Your name is: ");
for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
printf("%c", name[i]);
printf("\n");
printf("The sum of your name is: %d\n", sum);
return (0);
}
```

Comment: First of all `scanf("%c", name [i]);` must be `scanf("%c", &name [i]);`

Comment: `numbers[]` should be an int array or a similar decimal type of array.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use the fact that `'A'`, `'B'`, *etc* will be converted to sequential `int` values so you can map `'A'` to `1`, `'B'` to `2`, *etc* with something like this (use `toupper` to map `a` to `A`, *etc*):

```
char name [50];
int i, sum = 0;
scanf("%s", name);
for (i=0; i < strlen(name); ++i)
    sum += toupper(name[i]) - 'A' + 1;
```

Comment: right answer, but I would add an explanation about what `name[i] - 'A'` means, since OP's doesn't seem to know

Comment: Note: `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, etc are very commonly sequential codes, but not specified by C to be so.